# What does glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO); mean?

Tags: opengl, c++, graphics-programming

I need to write a description about a filter method I made but I don't know what `glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO);` means.

Comment: Do you have trouble finding this in the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml)?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. The basic documentation is readily available. If you're having trouble understanding something in the documentation, tell us what you found and where you are having trouble. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!